# What regularity guarantees existence of solutions to the Dirichlet problem for the Laplace equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain and $f \in C(\partial \Omega)$.

Consider the Dirichlet problem

$$\begin{cases}\Delta u=0&\text{ in } \Omega&\\u=f&\text{ on }\partial \Omega  \end{cases}$$

I know that, by Perron's method, if $\Omega$ satisfies an exterior sphere condition at each boundary point that we can generate a solution $u\in C(\overline{\Omega})\cap C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega)$ solution of the above.

But according to the Wikipedia page on the Dirichlet Problem, it claims we can guarantee a solution if $\partial \Omega \in C^{1,\alpha}$.

Can anyone provide a resource or proof of this fact?

Additionally, what can we say about the regularity of $u$ in this situation?